# Flutter nothing happens when button clicked more than once

Tags: flutter, bloc

**Hi, I am using a cubit for user sign up and when the register button is clicked once it works fine. If there is error and user is not routed to home page and I click the button again nothing happens.

See code below.

Please help!!!

**user_signup_cubit.dart**

```
import 'package:ach_mobile/main.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'user_signup_state.dart';

class UserSignupCubit extends Cubit<UserSignupState> {
  UserSignupCubit()
      : super(
          UserSignupInitial(),
        );

  Future<void> signupUser({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabaseInitialization.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password);
      if (response.user == null) {
        throw Exception('Pressure... no user.');
      }
      emit(UserSignupSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Failed to register user...'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**user_signup_state.dart****

```
part of 'user_signup_cubit.dart';

sealed class UserSignupState extends Equatable {
  const UserSignupState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class UserSignupInitial extends UserSignupState {}

final class UserSignupLoading extends UserSignupState {}

final class UserSignupSuccess extends UserSignupState {}

final class UserSignupFailed extends UserSignupState {
  final String error;

  const UserSignupFailed({required this.error});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}
```

**user_signup.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:ach_mobile/data_layer/cubits/user_signup/user_signup_cubit.dart';

class UserSignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserSignUp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => UserSignupCubit(),
      child: RegistrationForm(),
    );
  }
}

class RegistrationForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  RegistrationForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User Registration'),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<UserSignupCubit, UserSignupState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is UserSignupSuccess) {
            // Navigate to the next screen or perform necessary actions
          } else if (state is UserSignupFailed) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('Registration failed: ${state.error}'),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is UserSignupLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  TextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      final email = emailController.text;
                      final password = passwordController.text;
                      context.read<UserSignupCubit>().signupUser(
                            email: email,
                            password: password,
                          );
                    },
                    child: const Text('Register'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using a cubit and I tried using chat GPT for help but no help there.

Comment: You may need to see which lines are executed in the `signupUser` method. Try to use breakpoints in your IDE, or if not, just add some `print(...)` in each line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
Future<void> signupUser({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabaseInitialization.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password);
      if (response.user == null) {
        throw Exception('Pressure... no user.'); // <----- HERE
      }
      emit(UserSignupSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Failed to register user...'),
      );
    }
  }
```

Because when `response.user == null`, you just `throw` the error but do not handle it.

You can try:

```
  Future<void> signupUser(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabaseInitialization.auth
          .signUp(email: email, password: password);
      if (response.user == null) {
        emit(
          const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Your custom message...'),
        );
      } else {
        emit(UserSignupSuccess());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Failed to register user...'),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you emit the same state in a BLoC, the listeners might not be notified by default. When using BLoC with BlocBuilder or BlocListener, these widgets rely on changes in the state instance to trigger a rebuild or respond to changes.
Since you are emitting const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Failed to register user...')
**try**

```
import 'package:ach_mobile/main.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'user_signup_state.dart';

class UserSignupCubit extends Cubit<UserSignupState> {
  UserSignupCubit()
      : super(
          UserSignupInitial(),
        );

  Future<void> signupUser({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabaseInitialization.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password);
      if (response.user == null) {
        throw Exception('Pressure... no user.');
      }
      emit(UserSignupSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
//changed hereeee ---------------------------------------------------
      emit(
        const UserSignupFailed(error: 'Failed to register user... $email $password'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

try using different email or password.Cause that will change the content of state.